Error while using Swagger in springboot, Whitelabel Error Page
I'm trying to create a documentation using swagger for a project.
I run some test on an api, but when I go to the index page of swagger I get the following error:
**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Apr 18 11:25:03 CEST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

This is build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'TWEB'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

javadoc{
    destinationDir = file("/documentation")
    include 'main/**'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:+")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.12'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:+'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


Here is the SwaggerConfig class:
package TWEB.PostgreServer;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30) // or SWAGGER_2
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("TWEB.PostgreServer.clubs")) // Tell Springfox where your controllers are
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}

And this is the controller class which I'm trying to document:
package TWEB.PostgreServer.clubs;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class ClubsController {

    private final ClubsService clubsService;

    @Autowired
    public ClubsController(ClubsService clubsService) {
        this.clubsService = clubsService;
    }

    /*
     * This route is used to load the db values, the command that is supposed to use is:
     * curl -X POST http://localhost:8081/insert_clubs -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @json/clubsSwapped.json
     */

    @Operation(summary = "Insertion of the clubs values into the DB")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Clubs data insert into the DB")
    @PostMapping("/insert_clubs")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Clubs>> insertPlayers(@RequestBody List<Clubs> clubs) {
        List<Clubs> savedClubs = clubsService.saveClubs(clubs);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedClubs, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

...

Error
Project Structure

You get an error so you should have something in the server logs

What URL you are hitting?
